# How can we integrate Microsoft bot framework with SAP system as backend

Tags: frameworks, bots

Can anyone please tell how can we integrate Microsoft bot framework with SAP. Any documenattion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SAP has own Conversational AI, which mentions MS bot framework as a tool to integrate at https://cai.tools.sap/blog/five-steps-bot-building/ Maybe you can check that direction?